# Can an ASP.NET WebAPI action parameter be excluded from Swashbuckle/Swagger UI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

My actual case is I've allowed dependency injection using parameter binding on API controllers implementing a custom parameter binding.

For example, a controller action may look as follows:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetByIdAsync(Guid id, ICustomerFacade customerFacade)
```

When I explore my API using Swagger UI generated by Swashbuckle, `customerFacade` is specified as an actual and required resource action parameter.

Do you know any way of excluding controller action parameters from generated Swagger UI?

*Note: I know that a workaround could be injecting dependencies using constructor injection, but I still prefer to be able to both do constructor and regular method dependency injection.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive but I think you should be injecting the dependency into the controllers constructor and not the Get method.

So, your class would have:

```
private ICustomerFacade _customerFacade;

public MyController(ICustomerFacade customerFacade)
{
     _customerFacade = customerFacade;
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetByIdAsync(Guid id){
     return Ok(_customerFacade.getCustomer(id));
}
```

Unless you want the client calling your api to be responsible for injecting the customerFacade...